Failing Print on Kobra Max-2
I try to print a helmet on my Kobra Max 2, but I always get the same failure.
It prints really well for several ours, and then there are some layers which seem not to connect.
When I am printing smaller prints, everything is fine. Even print-in-place models with small failure tolerance print.
Material used: petg
My mate recommend to ask here, and here I am.


This looks an awful lot on issues with the filament feeding (filament entanglement causing temporary insufficient amount of filament flow). Does this happen every time at the same height or at different heights? We need more information to work with.

looks perfectly fine till the first rip... might your filament be uneven or the path being entangled in some way? Or might your Z-screw be somehow damaged in that area? A simple tower with height bands might help as a test

Thanks for the answers. It does not happen at the same height all the times. I printed a new Filament holder, because it could be that the spool entangled. I had not the time to start the print again yet.
